# Port block after i turn off the windows 2008 r2 server firewall

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall

I ran port scan and it shows port 25 closed.
I turn off the firewall and it shows port 25 closed.
I set an inbound rule and outbound rule in the firewall to allow port 25 and it shows closed.

I check group policy and firewall group policy is not configured, which means is not taking effect(i think)
I turn off the antivirus and repeated all the steps above.

What do I do to open port 25 in windows 2008 r2 server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a residential ISP? The majority of residential ISPs block port 25 to both prevent spam from compromised PCs and to ensure residential accounts aren't used for hosting.

You may want to check if your ISP blocks port 25 by researching online or contacting your ISP directly.

Comment: Not residential. This is a hospital.

Comment: By the way I cannot open ANY port.

Comment: @jvelez Then the question becomes are you connected directly to the WAN or is there another firewall between you and the WAN? As if you have no firewall restrictions (i.e. a telnet to port 25 via LAN is fine) and no blocking by the ISP or an upstream firewall you should obtain an incoming connection.